# Calculus, continuous functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I've been trying to improve my calculus skills, and i came upon this question that i am uncertain with how to start:

> Let $c \in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $c\neq 0$ be a ﬁxed number. Show, by verifying the $\epsilon-\delta$ deﬁnition, that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = \langle c,x\rangle$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: **HINT**: Do you know a formula relating $c\cdot x$ to $|c|$ and $|x|$?

Comment: Start by plugging this particular function in the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the  [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$|\langle c,x\rangle-\langle c,x_0\rangle|=|\langle c,x-x_0\rangle|\leq \|c\|\|x-x_0\|.$$
Hence for $\epsilon>0$,  if $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$ with $\delta:=\epsilon/\|c\|$ then
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|\langle c,x\rangle-\langle c,x_0\rangle|
\leq \|c\|\|x-x_0\|< \epsilon.$$

Comment: Not yet, im stuck on how the cauchy schwarz inequality ties in with the definition of continuity.

Comment: @freddie.l1 Recall the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuous function.

Comment: ahh i understand it now, thankyou very much for the help!